# How to create maven jar package including just dependencies

Tags: java, maven

I have a Maven `POM.xml` file including my classes dependencies. Using command `mvn clean compile assembly:single` I can create a fat executable jar with all dependencies. Now I'm wondering if I could create a non-executable jar including just dependencies in `POM.xml` and with no code or classes included?

Here is the `POM.xml` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Saprk</groupId>
    <artifactId>SparkPMUProcessing</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>SparkStreaming</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: so your trying to a single jar, which contains all the dependencies from pom.xml except your class right

Comment: @ArvindKatte Exactly!

Comment: you can use `<excludes>/path of jars<exclude>` this tags to exclude the jars from `pom.xml`.

Comment: share your code of `pom.xml`

Comment: @ArvindKatte Done!

Answer (score 0):

This can be also done using [maven shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html). Just configuration filters with include and exclude only required files.[Selecting Contents for Uber JAR](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html)

Comment: The link is not found!

Comment: Updated the link. hth

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a separate module for your dependencies. Your root `pom.xml` would look like this

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
    <module>core</module>
    <module>dependencies</module>
</modules>
```

Then in *dependencies* module's pom define all of yor dependencies and use `maven-assembly-plugin` like you do:

```
<dependencies>
    ...
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> 
                        <phase>package</phase> 
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And in your main module reference your *dependencies* module as a dependency